# Can we identify and Block all HTTP traffic without having access to HTTP Headers?

Tags: http, tcp, firewall

This is a network programming question. I need to block all HTTP traffic using a layer 4 firewall (i.e it can look headers only upto TCP/UDP layers ). Is this possible?

As I was searching for a more accurate answer , I got to know that even if we cannot access HTTP header, we can access HTTP message field using layer 4 firewall.

Comment: Next time, Please do not submit a question with a all caps title.

Comment: Are you programming a firewall or are you asking how to configure one?

Comment: This question may be more suited for serverfault, as its not programming related but more security

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, we made the same edit closely enough that SO didn't warn me that someone else modified it in flight, and we have the _same_ reputation. Crazy...

Comment: @sarnold Funny how both our edits went for nothing, as jmort253 got the final fix!.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, hehe, just so long as the caps are gone. :)

Comment: @jmort253 i am programming a firewall..

Answer (score 4):

No.

You can drop all TCP port 80 and port 443 traffic, but this might include traffic that isn't HTTP. (80 and 443 are open almost everywhere, so people (ab)use them often.) It will also miss HTTP traffic that happens on non-standard ports. (People do HTTP to port 8000 or 8080 or 8088 or 8888 all the time, in part because you don't need CAP_NET_BIND to be able to use high ports, in part because the numbers are easy to remember if port 80 is already used for something else.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the incoming port (ie 80) to detect HTTP traffic.

However you can't be 100% sure that's HTTP. But since it's the common port fort HTTP, I don't think many other applications use the port 80 for their communication.

If another port is used with HTTP protocol, you won't be able to block it this way, but it's a start.

Comment: A lot of applications use other ports along with HTTP Protocol, this is incorrect.

Comment: I'm not saying that HTTP is solely used on port 80, but that port 80 is rarely used with something else than HTTP... I'll rephrase my answer to be more clear.